# Realtime Database triggers executed multiple times on a value change?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Is there any guarantee that Realtime Database trigger is executed only once after a value changes?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

My exact scenario is:

- A Realtime database trigger in placed on a database node
- The node has value "A"
- **Multiple clients in parallel trigger a cloud function** that changes on a single value "A" to value "B".

While the value changes only once from A->B, I wouldn't be surprised if the tigger can be executed several times (just like for PubSub). Is there any docs on this?

Answer (score 0):

An update to the database that doesn't actually change any values shouldn't trigger any Cloud Functions, nor trigger any client side listeners on that data.  This is something you can pretty easily test for yourself.

If you're really worried about it, you can always compare the change snapshots in your function yourself, and return early before doing any work.

Comment: I am aware that without an actual change the trigger shouldn't be triggered, I refer here to general guarantees that Firebase Realtime Database tiggers offer. For instance PubSub triggers have a at-least-once guarantee, so they can be executed several times, for a single post (and it actually happens!). My function isn't idempotent, so I cannot allow this happen with the Realtime Database trigger.

Comment: That's not how I read your question.  Would you mind editing your question to rephrase it in terms of the actual concerns?  I read it as wondering if non-change updates (clients who make an update, but don't actually make changes) to the database would result in database triggers being invoked.  If you have an alternate situation, please ask accordingly.